# How to detect a color and print its name in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, colors

How can I detect dominant color on an image/cam and print its name?

eg: in image there can be, very light blue, light blue, blue, dark blue just because of lightning on that object or image when I analyze that image I want to make that I know dominant color is blue, and print "Blue" on screen. If I need to work with RGB I think I will need color ranges right?

ps: there can be also red, yellow etc on image but I want to detect dominant color.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (UIColor *)averageColor {

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    unsigned char rgba[4];
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rgba, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1), self.CGImage);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);  

    if(rgba[3] > 0) {
        CGFloat alpha = ((CGFloat)rgba[3])/255.0;
        CGFloat multiplier = alpha/255.0;
        return [UIColor colorWithRed:((CGFloat)rgba[0])*multiplier
                               green:((CGFloat)rgba[1])*multiplier
                                blue:((CGFloat)rgba[2])*multiplier
                               alpha:alpha];
    }
    else {
        return [UIColor colorWithRed:((CGFloat)rgba[0])/255.0
                               green:((CGFloat)rgba[1])/255.0
                                blue:((CGFloat)rgba[2])/255.0
                               alpha:((CGFloat)rgba[3])/255.0];
    }
}
```

from [Objective-c - Getting least used and most used color in a image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694618/objective-c-getting-least-used-and-most-used-color-in-a-image)

which is from http://www.bobbygeorgescu.com/2011/08/finding-average-color-of-uiimage/

Comment: Hi! Your code is excelent. But I keep getting the error: 
Property 'CGImage' not found on object of type 'MyClass*'
What can be done? Please! =)

Comment: You are not calling this on the correct object, your image needs to be an UIImage and this extension will allow you to call [image averageColor].