# Property 'CGImage' not found on object of type 'MyClass *'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-image

I am developing an iOS App that needs to recognize colors and other stuff.
I got this code:

```
- (UIColor *)averageColor {

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
unsigned char rgba[4];
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rgba, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1), self.CGImage);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGContextRelease(context);  

if(rgba[3] > 0) {
    CGFloat alpha = ((CGFloat)rgba[3])/255.0;
    CGFloat multiplier = alpha/255.0;
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:((CGFloat)rgba[0])*multiplier
                           green:((CGFloat)rgba[1])*multiplier
                            blue:((CGFloat)rgba[2])*multiplier
                           alpha:alpha];
}
else {
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:((CGFloat)rgba[0])/255.0
                           green:((CGFloat)rgba[1])/255.0
                            blue:((CGFloat)rgba[2])/255.0
                           alpha:((CGFloat)rgba[3])/255.0];
}
}
```

from this guy: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22838941/11703579)

It's 99% perfect, except from this line:

```
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1), self.CGImage);
```

In which I get the following error message:

`Property 'CGImage' not found on object of type 'MyClass *'`

As far as I know, the CGImage is part of the `CoreImage` Framework, which is correctly added on the project, and (I believe so) correctly imported in the class. Check out my imports.

```
#import "MyClass.h"
#import "TiUtils.h"
#import "TiViewProxy.h"
#import <TitaniumKit/TiBlob.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreImage/CIImage.h>
```

Please, what is wrong? What can I do for the error to go away?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `CG` is the prefix of CoreGraphics.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I imported `#import <CoreGraphics/CGImage.h>` ,  but the error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is (most likely) a category (in Swift nomenclature 'extension' ) on `UIImage`.

Technically it would work on anything that responded to the selector `CGImage`.

The full declaration should be something like:

**UIImage + ColorHelp.h**

```
@interface UIImage (ColorHelp)

- (UIColor *)averageColor;

@end
```

**UIImage + ColorHelp.m**

```
@implementation UIImage (ColorHelp)

- (UIColor *)averageColor {
   //stuff
}

@end
```

Create a new "Objective-C File" in Xcode to create a template category on `UIImage`.

Fromm there all instances of `UIImage` will respond to average color. e.g

```
UIImage *myImage = <something>;
UIColor *averageColor = [myImage averageColor];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So, I have to create the template, and then implement my method inside the .m file. And then I have to use it on other classes creating an object reference to it? Right?

Comment: If you implement the code as described **any** instance of `UIImage` will answer to `averageColor`.  I assume somewhere in `MyClass` you have a reference to the `UIImage` you are trying to analyse?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I'm using an instance of it on MyClass, and it's working perfectly now. Thanks man!

Comment: If you can (and want to), please upvote my question =)