# Detecting background colour of a UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I am working on an app that loads images from my server. These images are all different sizes. So I was wondering - it is possible to detect the background colour of an image or its most prominent colour?

The reason behind this is I would like the UIView behind the UIImage to change its background colour based on the UIImage. So for example say I have a UIImage that has an iPhone sitting on a blue table  I would like to detect that colour blue and use it as the background colour for the UIView.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147779/how-do-i-release-a-cgimageref-in-ios/12148136#12148136

Comment: what you can do is get the **average color** of that `UIImage` and then set the `UIView`'s color to that **average Color**

Comment: You can get average color using this method.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13695592/1042240

Comment: Going on from this - is it possible to get the average colour for  a part of the UIImage - say the left top corner or left side of the image?